# How to modify list property without affecting other list property of same type?

Tags: c#, .net, list

Here is my sample code,

```
List<myClass> myclass1 = new List<myClass>();
List<myClass> myclass2 = new List<myClass>();
//add data to myClass1 from source
foreach (myClass data in source)
  myclass1.Add(data);
//add data to myClass2 from source
foreach (myClass data in source)
  myclass2.Add(data);

//Change name property only for myclass1
foreach (myClass data in myclass1)
data.Name = "Test";
```

After changing name property for `myclass1` object, its also modfiying the value of name property of `myclass2` to 'Test'. What is the reason & how do I avoid it?

Comment: you are adding a reference to each of those lists, so they both point to the same object. To achieve what you want you need to create a new instance of the object and add it to the second list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List is storing by reference, make temp object and add to the list.

```
foreach(myClass data in source)
{
    myClass tmpData = new myClass(){
        Something = data.Something;            
    };
    myClass1.Add(tmpData);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because you put the same thing into both lists!

If you want the contents of each list to be different, then don't put the same thing into it.

If `myClass` implements `IClonable`, then you can use

```
foreach (myClass data in source)
  myclass1.Add((myClass)data.Clone());
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because `data` is same in both lists.

To achieve you need to put different data in second list as below :-

```
var source2 = source.clone();

    foreach (myClass data in source2 )
      myclass2.Add(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you use reference types which means you only put the reference of the instance to the list so basicly you have to list containing the same elements. You can use value types but if it has reference type fields it will still reference to the same object instance in it.
You colud try to clone or serislise and deserislize the object but after the list won't contain the elements from the source just the copy of them.

Answer (score 0):

`myClass` is reference type. For solving this problem you should add to second list copies of `data`.

Answer (score 0):

Learn more about difference between value types and reference types and how they work in c#.

Check this : [What is the difference between a reference type and value type in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057267/what-is-the-difference-between-a-reference-type-and-value-type-in-c)